# How to protect a DC motor from high voltage?

Tags: motor

I have a 1.5V DC motor.  I'm making a project where I will use a 9V battery.   How can I protect the motor from the high voltage?

How much current is needed for DC motors to work?

I tried using different resistors but none of them worked, the motor didn't turn and the resistors became extremely hot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also realize that a 9 V battery is not designed to deliver much current. Your motor might need more current than a 9 V battery can deliver.  *And how much current is needed for dc motors to work?* There are **HUGE** differences in the current required to run a DC motor. Strong/large motors typically need a lot more current than a small and weak miniature motor. So look up or measure what your motor needs.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: DC motors need as much current as their specifications say they need. Current X Voltage = Power. Electrical Power = Mechanical Power + Losses. Mechanical Power = Torque X Speed X Measurement Unit Constant. Speed is proportional to voltage. Torque is proportional to current. Resistance connected in series with a motor has very limited usefulness, it can easily waste as much power as the motor requires. You probably need to study a bit. This site can only answer specific questions, it can not provide complete lessons on any general area of knowledge.

Comment: The solution is to use a 1.5V battery or buy a 9V motor.

Answer (score 1):

At least some help is what you need. :-)

> how much current is needed for dc motors to work.

1.5V motor is likely a brushed/linear motor. The easist approach is; measure the stall current.

1. Measure the resistance (**Rm**) across the two wire/terminal while the motor is in "stop", no spin, "lock the rotor".
2. The maximum current it needs is **I_max = 1.5V / Rm**. While the motor is spinning, the current depends on the torque/loading.

> tried using different resistors but non of them worked, the motor
> didn't turn and the resistors became extremely hot.

External resistor (**Rex**) to limit the current: 
9V = (Rex + Rm) * I_max ==> **Rex = (9V / I_max) - Rm**

The resistor(Rex) size/Wattage Wex = Vex x I_max, and Vex = Rex * I_max 
**Wex = Rex * I_max * I_max**

Use a resistor with larger (x1.5 to x3) Wattage than calculated. Use heat-sink, if the wattage goes over 0.5W (random pick).